# NestJs can't resolve dependencies of commandhandler

Tags: typescript, nestjs, cqrs

I'm getting the following error while trying to get my module working:

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ReceiveChatLineCommandHandler (?, Repository). Please make sure that the argument EventPublisher at index [0] is available in the SmershModule context.`

here is what my code looks like:

`smersh.module.ts`

```
@Module({
    imports: [CqrsModule<Event>],
    controllers: [
        LandingPageController,

        CurrentStatusController,
        CurrentChatController,

        PlayersController,
        PlayerController,
        CondemnPlayerController,

        LayoutController
    ],
    providers: [
        Repository,
       ...CommandHandlers,
       ...EventHandlers
    ]
})
export class SmershModule implements OnModuleInit {

    

    public log : FileLogger

    public onModuleInit(): void {
        this.log = new FileLogger(`./info-${new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}-${this.constructor.name}.log`)
        this.log.info('smersh module initiated', this)
    }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
    imports: [SmershModule],
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

`ReceiveChatLineCommandHandler.ts`

```
@CommandHandler(ReceiveChatLineCommand)
export class ReceiveChatLineCommandHandler implements ICommandHandler<ReceiveChatLineCommand> {
    constructor(
        protected readonly publisher: EventPublisher,
        protected readonly repository: Repository
    ) {
    }

    async execute(command : ReceiveChatLineCommand) {
        const { Id, Line, Date } = command
        const domain = this.publisher.mergeObjectContext(await this.repository.Get<RoundSearchReport, Round>(Id))
        domain.receiveChatLine(Line, Date)
        domain.commit();

    }
}
```

`index.ts`

```
import { ReceiveChatLineCommandHandler } from './Round'

export const CommandHandlers =  [
    ReceiveChatLineCommandHandler
]
```

dependency injection is working for the controllers just not the commandhandlers, what am i doing wrong?

I've tried importing the cqrs module in app.module.ts, also tried importing just one commandhandler seperately, both didnt work.

Comment: Please provide the module's class in which you have defined `ReceiveChatLineCommandHandler` as a provider.

Comment: i got it working temporarily by reinstalling the nestjs packages but after a rebuild of one of my projects it went back to not working.